# Is there a direct flight from Sucre to Uyuni in Bolivia?

Tags: bolivia

I've seen various references on online forums and websites to a direct flight from Sucre to Uyuni in Bolivia provided by Amaszonas since September 2017. But I cannot verify this. Does a direct flight exist?

Comment: I sure don't see one on their web site!

Comment: I don't think that route is offered as a non-stop anymore. It used to be once daily M/W/F but now on those days I can only find an option with a long connection in La Paz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazonas used to be the airline that did this.  However, [their route map](https://www.amaszonas.com/en-us/destinations/amaszonas-route-map) now shows this is no longer the case. Flight searches on search engines all seem to support this - you have to hop via say, Cochabamba or La Paz.